# 2FA on phpmyadmin 4.8.4

Tags: database, security, authentication, phpmyadmin, database-security

I am trying to implement Two factor authentication (2FA) on phpmyadmin. Conifguration Storage has been setup and corresponding user has been created. However, when I go to Settings > Two Factor Authentication and select the Authentication Application (2FA) option, phpmyadmin throws the following error :

Error in processing request
Error code: 500
Error text: error (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.

If anyone has implemented or faced the issue, kindly help me resolve the same.

[image: Error]

Comment: Usually an error 500 is logged in your webserver error log, could you please tell us what is logged there? From where have you installed phpMyAdmin — did you download directly from phpmyadmin.net or are you using a package manager or some other prepackaged kit?

Answer (score -1):

Is there any active firewall rules? Once I had a phpmyadmin on AWS ec2 and I was using AWS security groups, by only letting 3306 open I wasn't able to activate 2fa.

Comment: I've enabled all trafic to my IP address.